# Throw Exception With BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, swing

is there a way to throw an exception with

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/castle.jpg")))
```

This solves my problem with reading images from a .jar file. But the problem is it doesn't throw an exception. 
It is weird that read throws an exception for

```
ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/castle.jpg").toString()))
```

Is there a way? I have tried to make it work for eclipse and .jar but nothing works!
And I hate to keep checking for nulls

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you meaning [Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) ?, for example

```
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(YourClassName.class.getResource("resources/image.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(YourClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that? To include the resource directly into read... I doubt it throws an exception. I will try it now :)

Comment: It works! I don't understand, the API said getResource throws an exception for a null string. I thought it meant the literal null. Ugh! Thanks a lot. Hopefully it would work with a .jar file!

Comment: be sure, that works for .jar file, rest is here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/index.html